# Add Node at begin and end of the existing xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I generated a XML file through API call then I tried to read the file using XML source component in ssis but it is read only data sets except all data contains in file .

Here my file

```
<?XML version 1.0 >
 <ABC>
      <a>info<a/>
 <ABC/>
```

But I want file like below then only I can easily read file using component 
We can manipulate the file manually for single file but not for thousand files

```
<?XML Version 1.0>
<X>
  <ABC>
      <a>info <a/>
  <ABC/>
</X>
```

How to add that 'X' node to the existing file .

I am not having much exposure on .Net technology .

Kindly help me at the earliest of time .

Thank You 
KiranKumar

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                    "<ABC>" +
                        "<a>info</a>" +
                    "</ABC>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement root = doc.Root;
            root.ReplaceWith(new XElement("X", root));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try streaming API.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("test2.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("X");
    reader.MoveToContent();
    writer.WriteNode(reader.ReadSubtree(), true);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

This approach handles xml without excessive memory consumption.

Also, this method allows to modify xml on the fly, getting it from the input API stream and writing to output stream.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream))
```